# No module named 'pysvn._pysvn'

Tags: python-3.7, pysvn

On ubuntu18.04, 
I installed pysvn by using :

```
sudo apt-get install python3-svn
```

The module is present by running help("modules") in a venv with python3.7

But when I ran my script I had an error saying that:

`/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pysvn/__init__.py": ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysvn._pysvn'`

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: If you ran it in a venv, you need to install it in that venv!

Comment: but when I created venv, I used --system-site-packages so it should be good